# 2d array finished mine sweeper board program

Tags: c++

Hello I am attempting to write a program and I seem to be stick. This program is in the end supposed to display two variants of a single 10 by 10 mine sweeper board. One of which where if there is a mine in that location it displays an asterisk(*) and if there is no mine it displays a period. The second variant also needs to display an asterisk where the mines are located on the board. But instead of a period it has to display the number of mines located 1 space away in any direction. I can't seem to think of how to easily write a program that will add up each of the mines located around each point. I also can't figure out why my program asks the initial question twice even if it meets the criteria for stopping the loop the first time around.

```
/*
Program: minesweeper(sort of)
The intention of this program is to display essentially two mine sweeper game boards one of which displays a *
where all of the mines would be located and a . where no mines are located. Then the second display 
should display a * where all of the mines are and then display a number based on how many mines surround that space.
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
double get_probability();
int plant_mines(bool mineCells[10][10], double prob);
int print(bool mineCells[10][10]);
int count_mines(bool mineCells[10][10], int mineCounters[10][10]);
int main()
{
    //used to hold true if there is a mine located at said location or false if there is no mine
    bool mineCells[10][10];
    //used to hold a value of -5 if the corrosponding value on mineCells is true and if the corrosponding value on
    //minecells is false it should add up and hold the value of how many mines are surroudning it.
    int mineCounters[10][10];
    get_probability();
    double prob = get_probability();
    plant_mines(mineCells, prob);
    print(mineCells);

    int stop;
    cin >> stop;
    return 0;
}
//asks the user for a number between 0 and 1 to use as the probability of mines apearing laster on.
double get_probability()
{
    double prob;
    bool repeat;
do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 1: ";
        cin >> prob;
    //should execute once asking the user for a input between 0 and 1 and if the input is not between those two it shoud
    //then continue to repeat untill the permaiters set in the question are met.
        if (prob >= 0 && prob <= 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            repeat = true;
        }
}while (repeat = true);
    return prob;
}
//takes the probability given by the user and then uses it to generate that percentage of mines on the field
int plant_mines(bool mineCells[10][10], double prob)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
        {
            //generates a random number between 0 and 1 and sets it equal to the variable random
            double random = static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
            //is the variable random is less than or equal to the probability then the array is set to true meaning
            //there is a mine located at that position
            if (random <= prob)
            {
                mineCells[count][counter] = true;
            }
            //iff the random number is greater than the user input than there is no mine located at said position
            else
            {
                mineCells[count][counter] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return mineCells[10][10];
}
//Should count up the mines surronding the location to be output later on
//(the mines surrounding the location do include all mines 1 space diagonal, vertical and horizontal from said location)
int count_mines(bool mineCells[10][10], int mineCounters[10][10])
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
        {
            if (mineCells[count][counter] == 1)
            {
                mineCounters[count][counter] = 0;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
//displays a * where ever a mine is locate and a . where ever a mine is not located
int print(bool mineCells[10][10])
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
        {
            if (mineCells[count][counter] == 1)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ".";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Intial question problem, wrong condition check inside `while()`. You should use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: SO works best when you ask one question at a time, and cut your code down to a [mcve].